# Supervised Text Similarity

Tags: python, r, nlp, quanteda

I am trying to calculate text similarity between sentences. I have standardized medical services list containing text of service ( for e.g. consultation of neurologist). Every time hospital/clinic comes with their own service list so I need to map hospital's service list with standardized service list. I calculate TF-IDF cosine similarity between hospital's service with standardized service list using skip-gram tokens. I have been doing this for long time so I also have correct mapping of services of some 15 hospitals. By 'correct mapping', I mean medical experts from my organization provided correct mapping of services which are wrongly labelled or mapped using tf-idf cosine similarity algorithm. I want to use 'correct mapping' as text classification problem but no. of labels in this case is more than 10K. Is there a way to perform 'Supervised text similarity'? I tried word2vec algorithm but it does not incorporate supervised element (i.e. target variable (correct mapping of previous results)). Currently I am using R. I am open for Python as well.

See the example of my datasets below ( consider `A as 'standardized service list', B as 'hospital's service list', C as 'correct mapping'`) .

```
A <- data.frame(name= c("Patient had X-ray right leg arteries.",
                         "Subject was administered Rgraphy left shoulder",
                         "Exam consisted of x-ray leg arteries",
                         "Patient administered x-ray leg with 20km distance."),
                row.names = paste0("A", 1:4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
B <- data.frame(name= c(B = "Patient had X-ray left leg arteries",
                         "Rgraphy right shoulder given to patient",
                         "X-ray left shoulder revealed nothing sinister",
                         "Rgraphy right leg arteries tested"), 
                row.names = paste0("A", 1:4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

C <- data.frame(name= c("Patient had X-ray right leg arteries.",
                         "Subject was administered Rgraphy left shoulder",
                         "Exam consisted of x-ray leg arteries",
                         "Patient administered x-ray leg with 20km distance."),
                mapping = c("Radiography right leg artery.",
                            "Radiography left shoulder",
                            "Radiography leg arteries",
                            "Radiography leg with more than 10km distance."),
                row.names = paste0("A", 1:4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you mean classification instead of similarity? I would understand similarity as using similar words. TF-IDF cosine similarity seems like a good approach for that. `quanteda` has a few more methods in `textstat_simil()`. `RTextTool` implements a few machine learning algorithms for classification. But it hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: Thanks. I mean text similarity only. Idea to use 'correct mapping' list of services to find synonyms which can later be used for semantic matching.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use the ruimtehol R package at: https://github.com/bnosac/ruimtehol it provides text similarities by providing embeddings for sentences/documents/supervised/unsupervised or a combination of both. 
But you should really try it out and provide code where you show how to use the package. Now you just provide data and hope that someone else will provide code for your question.